# How do I make jQuery work after an AJAX call

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I've read a few posts on this, but none gave a ***specific*** answer (or the questions were unnecessarily complicated...). I will keep it simple.

I am using jQuery UI for a draggable/droppable function. When a draggable is dropped on the target element, an AJAX function is called. It all works fine, but only once. When I try it again, I can't even drag the element anymore. Here is my (simplified) code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".item").draggable();
    $(".target").droppable({
        drop: function(){
            AjaxFunction(var1, var2);
        }            
    });
});
```

This is the simplified AjaxFunction:

```
function AjaxFunction (var1, var2) {
    var url = "ajax/script.php";
    var data = {position: var1, tag: var2};
    $.post(url, data, function(data) {
        $(".target").html(data).show(); 
    });
}
```

Can anyone give me a specific solution to the above code on how to make it work?

Comment: What does the AjaxFunction do exactly?

Comment: are your bindings lost? try to rebind it in the drop: callback

Comment: > ron: the AJAX function updates .target

Comment: > Barry: can you please copy and edit the code please?

Comment: How specifically is the `.target` updated?

Comment: > Jacob: please check the edited post

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you've shown. Your problem is likely elsewhere. Can you create an example on jsfiddle.net that has the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refer to this post:

[Jquery Draggable - How do I create a new draggable div on the fly that can then be dragged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927662/jquery-draggable-how-do-i-create-a-new-draggable-div-on-the-fly-that-can-then)

Specifically this part:

```
$(element).draggable('disable');
```

and

```
$(element).draggable('enable');
```

It is not exactly the same but it gives some insight on the problem. Basically, you may want to try disabling draggable and droppable, then re-enabling them after your ajax success.

```
function AjaxFunction (var1, var2) {
    var url = "ajax/script.php";
    var data = {position: var1, tag: var2};
    $.post(url, data, function(data) {
        $(".item").draggable("destroy");
        $(".target").droppable("destroy");

        $(".target").html(data).show().droppable({revert:true});
        $(".item").draggable();
    });
}
```

Comment: hey kai, thanks for the link. I read the post, but I don't see how it's applicable here. how would you apply it? can you maybe amend the code snippet from my post above? would be great